# castle windsor register a generic interface and retrieve all registered instances the inherit indirectly from it

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have the following structure -

```
public interface IBaseInterface<T>
{
}

public interface IChildInterface1<Class1> : IBaseInterface<Class1>
{
}

public interface IChildInterface2<Class2> : IBaseInterface<Class2>
{
}

public class ImplementationClass1 : IChildInterface1<Class1>
{
}

public class ImplementationClass2 : IChildInterface2<Class2>
{
}
```

I want to register all types in the assembly that implement IBaseInterface directly or indirectly, so I want to be able to register ImplementationClass1 and ImplementationClass2 given IBaseInterface. And then I want to retrieve any concrete type based on the generic type definition of ChildInterface classes.

I am registering types like this -

```
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<Class1>()
            .BasedOn(typeof(IBaseInterface<>))
            .WithService.Base()
            .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient)
     );
```

and then resolving the type using

```
var impl = container.Resolve(typeof(IChildInterface1<>))
```

I expected this to give me an instance of ImplementationClass1, however I get the error -

No component for supporting the service IChildInterface`1 was found

Can someone figure out what I am doing wrong, is this even a valid scenario that I am attempting?

This is my whole code -

```
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;

namespace complexresolutionioc
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();

      container.Register(
        AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<Class1>()
              .BasedOn(typeof(IBaseInterface<>))
              .WithService.AllInterfaces()
              .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient)
     );

      var thisWorks = container.Resolve<IChildInterface1<Class2>>();
    }
  }

  public interface IBaseInterface<T>
  {
  }

  public interface IChildInterface1<Class1> : IBaseInterface<Class1>
  {
  }

  public interface IChildInterface2<Class2> : IBaseInterface<Class2>
  {
  }

  public class ImplementationClass1 : IChildInterface1<Class1>
  {
  }

  public class ImplementationClass2 : IChildInterface2<Class2>
  {
  }

  public class Class1 { }
  public class Class2 { }

}
```

gives me this error -

No component for supporting the service complexresolutionioc.IChildInterface1`1[[complexresolutionioc.Class2, complexresolutionioc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] was found
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1ab5e0b25b145b19\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel_Resolve.cs:line 172
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve(Type service) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1ab5e0b25b145b19\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:line 889
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.ResolveT in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1ab5e0b25b145b19\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:line 978
   at complexresolutionioc.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\MyDev\complexresolutionioc\complexresolutionioc\Program.cs:line 21

-ilias

Comment: you're trying to resolve open generic type?

Comment: yes, is that not possible in this case?

Comment: This is not possible in any case. You can't get an object that is an instance of open generic type. `var list = new List<>();` does not work.

Comment: that's true, however I don't want an instance of the open generic type, I have registered concrete implementations that I want the container to resolve for me. I have updated the original question to hopefully make it more clear. (And thanks for taking the time to look at this)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide closed generic type you want to resolve:

```
var thisWorks = container.Resolve<IChildInterface1<Class2>>();
```

Comment: thanks. but still no luck unfortunately, I have now included the whole code in my question. I think I am doing something wrong during registration.